# Pair items in a list with one another in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I want to pair items in a list with one another

Example

```
list("A","B","C") to -> list(Pair(A,B),Pair(A,C),Pair(B,C))

list("A","B","C","D") to -> list(Pair(A,B),Pair(A,C),Pair(A,D),Pair(B,C),Pair(B,D),Pair(C,D))
```

I have tried using `zipWithNext`, but it does not help my cause. If anyone can show me how I can achieve this?

Comment: I assume you're looking for the [Cartesian product](https://www.mathstopia.net/sets/cartesian-product), correct?

Comment: @grooveplex, more like carthesian product of set with itself, excluding pairs with identical elements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply nest `for` loops and use ranges for that:

```
fun permute(list: List<String>): List<Pair<String, String>> {
    var result: MutableList<Pair<String, String>> = mutableListOf()

    for (i in 0..(list.size - 1)) {
        val s = list.get(i)

        for (j in (i + 1)..(list.size - 1)) {
            val p = Pair(s, list.get(j))
            result.add(p)
        }
    }

    return result
}
```

There might be ways that are *more Kotlin style*, but I don't know one at the moment...

Using this method in a `fun main()` like this

```
fun main() {
    val list = listOf("A", "B", "C", "D")

    println(permute(list))
}
```

will output

```
[(A, B), (A, C), (A, D), (B, C), (B, D), (C, D)]
```

Answer (score 2):

kotlin way )

```
var a = listOf("A", "B", "C", "D")

var pairs = a.mapIndexed { index, s ->
        a.slice(index + 1 until a.size).map { Pair(s, it)}
}.flatten()


print(pairs)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you were looking for a **Pair chaining** here is how to do it:

```
fun main() {

    val a = listOf("A", "B", "C", "D")
    val listPair: MutableList<Pair<String, String>> = mutableListOf()

    a.forEachIndexed{ index, _ -> 
            if (index != a.size - 1) {
                val pair = Pair(a.get(index), a.get(index + 1))
                listPair.add(pair)
            }
        }

    println(listPair)
}
```

Result: **[(A, B), (B, C), (C, D)]**